# Issue with saving VisualForcePage with remote javascripting

Tags: javascript-remoting

Seems to be an issue getting my VF page to save when doing simple JS Remoting.  Here is the controller.

```
global class Events_Ext{


    @RemoteAction
    global static List<singleEvent> getDayEvents(String datex){
    // datex has format YYYY-MM-DD
    Integer y = Integer.valueOf((datex.split('-'))[0]) ;
    Integer m = Integer.valueOf((datex.split('-'))[1]) ;
    Integer d = Integer.valueOf((datex.split('-'))[2]) ;

    DateTime startOfDay = DateTime.newInstance(y,m,d,0,0,0);
    DateTime endOfDay = DateTime.newInstance(y,m,d,23,59,59);

    Event [] dayEvents = [select Subject,Description,Location,StartDateTime,EndDateTime from Event where Owner.Name = 'Innovation Calendar' and StartDateTime >= :startOfDay and StartDateTime <= :endOfDay] ;

    List<singleEvent> retVal = new List<singleEvent> () ;
    for (Event e : dayEvents) {
        retVal.add (new singleEvent(e.Subject, e.Description, String.valueOf(e.StartDateTime.time()), String.valueOf(e.EndDateTime.time()), e.Location)) ;
    }
    return retVal ;
    }

global class singleEvent {

    public String subject {set;get;} 
    public String descx {set;get;} 
    public String stime {set;get;} 
    public String etime {set;get;} 
    public String location {set;get;} 

    public singleEvent (String s, String d, String st, String et, String l) {
        subject = s ;
        descx = d ;
        stime = st ;
        etime = et ;
        location = l ;  
    }
}
}
```

And here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="Events_ext">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getEvents() {

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.Events_ext.getDayEvents}',
        '2014-22-05',
        function(result, event){
            alert(event.status ? 'Success' : event.message);
        });
    }
    </script>


    <button onclick="getEvents()">Get Events</button>
    <div id="responseErrors"></div>


</apex:page>
```

When I try and Save, I get these errors:

> Error: /apex/caltest1: No remoted actions found for
>   'Events_ext.getDayEvents'  Error: No remoted actions found for
>   'Events_ext.getDayEvents'

Anyone seen this before?

Thx,
Hamayoun

Edited to add:

Instead of using Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction, I used this instead:

```
Events_ext.getDayEvents(
        '2014-22-05',
        function(result, event){
            alert(event.status ? 'Success' : event.message);
        });
    }
```

Now it saves, but when I run it I get a javascript error: "Events_ext is not defined".

Comment: Is the `Events_Ext` class in an org that has a namespace defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried Events_Ext ... I wonder if it is a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: Looks like it is - a page with $RemoteAction.Events_Ext.getDayEvents will save.

Comment: The syntax tried should definitely work, but JS is case sensitive like most programming languages. Getting used to Apex can be a killer in that regard :)